# pathForResource of file created within app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ftp

I've implemented a bit of functionality that uploads a file created within the app to an FTP location, however the 'pathForResource' returns an error where it cannot find the filepath for the resource.

This is the code i'm using:

```
 SCRFTPRequest *ftpRequest = [[SCRFTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://79.170.44.42"] 
                                                  toUploadFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.htmlFilePath ofType:@"text/html"]];
```

I've been able to upload files that are packaged with my app, for example, files that are standard 'info.plist etc'. How would I be able to specify the location of a file that is created within the app? Do I need to give a full resource path instead of just referencing the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource]` will only work for files that you added to the XCode Project. You need to look for the file right where you stored it when it was created.

Comment: What could I use for files that are created within the app?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2